# Regex: Specified words in any order

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not good at regex, trying to make 2 regex.

**Regex1:**

> All specified words in any order but nothing else. (repetition
>   allowed).

**Regex2:**

> All specified words in any order but nothing else.
>   (repetition not allowed).

**Words**:

```
aaa, bbb, ccc
```

**Strings**:

```
aaa ccc bbb
aaa ccc
aaa bbb ddd ccc
bbb aaa bbb ccc
```

**Regex1** evaluate above strings as:

```
true -> all word present in any order
false -> bbb is missing
false -> unknown word 'ddd'
false -> repetition not allowed
```

**Regex2** evaluate above strings as:

```
true -> all word present in any order
false -> bbb is missing
false -> unknown word 'ddd'
true -> all word present in any order and repetition is allowed
```

**My Attempt**

```
/^(?=.*\baaa\b)(?=.*\bbbb\b)(?=.*\bccc\b).*$/
```

Asking for learning purpose so please elaborate it.

Comment: So some chars like spaces are allowed to exist between words? What else could be there?

Comment: only spaces, newline, tabs are allowed.

Comment: Are you sure about newlines to exist between words?

Comment: k my bad, i guess i got wrong concept of `\b`

Comment: @revo only space and tabs are allowed.

Comment: Please check this https://regex101.com/r/Olu2kI/1

Comment: Just because you can use a regex doesn't mean you should. `var input = "ccc aaa ccc bbb";
var words = input.split(" ");
var uniqueWords = Array.from(new Set(words));
console.log(uniqueWords.sort().join(" ") === "aaa bbb ccc");`

Comment: @EricDuminil yes u r correct we can solve this without regex but i'm learning regex as i described in my question. just want to explore new ways to write regex so in future i can solve some complex validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Regex 1:**

```js
var re = /^(?=.*?\baaa\b)(?=.*?\bbbb\b)(?=.*?\bccc\b)\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b(?: +\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b)*$/;
var res = document.getElementById('result');
res.innerText += re.test('aaa ccc bbb');
res.innerText += ', ' + re.test('aaa ccc ddd');
res.innerText += ', ' + re.test('aaa ddd bbb');
res.innerText += ', ' + re.test('ccc bbb ccc');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Your code already does part of the trick. Your positive lookaheads check that all words appear somewhere, however not, that they are the only words present. To achieve this, I added the circumflex (^) at the beginning to detect the start of the string. Then, the non capturing group of `\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b`, to detect the first instance of any word.
This is then followed by any number of words, preceded by at least one space `(?:\s+\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b)*`, basically the same pattern, but with the \s+ in front, and wrapped in a *. And then we need the string to end somewhere. This is done with the dollar sign `$`.

**For Regex 2:**

The basic strategy is the same. You would just check with a negative lookahead, that the matched string does not exist again:

```js
//var re = /^(?=.*?\baaa\b)(?!.*?\baaa\b.*?\baaa\b)(?=.*?\bbbb\b)(?!.*?\bbbb\b.*?\bbbb\b)(?=.*?\bccc\b)(?!.*?\bccc\b.*?\bccc\b)\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b(?:\s+\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b)*$/;
// optimized version, see comments
var re = /^(?=.*?\baaa\b)(?=.*?\bbbb\b)(?=.*?\bccc\b)(?!.*?\b(\w+)\b.*?\b\1\b)\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b(?: +\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b)*$/;
var res = document.getElementById('result');
res.innerText += re.test('aaa ccc bbb');
res.innerText += ', ' + re.test('aaa ccc ddd');
res.innerText += ', ' + re.test('aaa bbb aaa');
res.innerText += ', ' + re.test('aaa ccc bbb ccc');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

First, we have the positive lookahead `(?=.*?\bword\b)` to see that word exists. We follow that by the negative lookahead `(?!.*?\baaa\b.*?\baaa\b)` to see, the word does not exist multiple times. Repeat for all words. Presto!

**Update**: Instead of checking the specific words aren't repeated, we can also check that NO word is repeated by using the `(?!.*?\b(\w+)\b.*?\b\1\b)` construct. This makes the regex more concise. Thanks to @revo for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry, my regex expertise comes from years of practice. You need to get to know your tools, i.e. check ALL available constructs, especially the negation possibilities using either negative character classes `[^abcd]` or negative lookahead/lookbehind assertions (in the example). They are very powerful, but need to be well understood to function as desired. After that, it's piecing things together and a bit of trial and error :-)

Comment: k u r right. i need to learn negations, lookaround assertions effectively, thnx for your help.

Comment: You could remove all those negative lookaheads in favor of `(?!.*?\b(\w+)\b.*?\b\1\b)`

Comment: and you shouldn't use `\s` otherwise it will mess up with multiline input strings.

Comment: @revo: AFAI understood the question, we are looking for specific words, not just any words. Also, the `\s` should also capture newlines and carriage returns, so things should not be messed up. That is, if we allow CR and LF as separators.

Comment: Ah, ok, I get it now. First look for all specific words, then check that NO word exists twice. Yes, nice optimization.

Comment: You're matching an input string with only `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc` out of lookarounds so it means we are not looking for other words, hence the short lookahead does the job. Also `.*?` doesn't go beyond newlines but later you are telling newlines are OK to be matched by `\s`.

Comment: See it here to understand how your regex behaves on multiline input strings https://regex101.com/r/5EMjEN/1

Comment: Lookarounds orders isn't important at all. It is `(?=.*\baaa\b)(?=.*\bbbb\b)(?=.*\bccc\b)(?!.*?\b(\w+)\b.*?\1)` but it could be `(?!.*?\b(\w+)\b.*?\1)(?=.*\baaa\b)(?=.*\bbbb\b)(?=.*\bccc\b)`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. We should add the `s` modifier at the end of the regex to get rid of this inconsistency.

Comment: No you should exclude newlines from being matched.

Comment: Ah, just found out that JS does not offer the `s` modifier, so, yes, we should exclude newline from matching.

Comment: Beginning from ECAMScript 2018 `s` modifer is added. However you can use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` anytime to bring the same behavior.

Comment: can you guys tell me which one regex i should use.

Comment: It depends on your use case. Do you want duplicates or not?

Comment: @shajji The first regex allows repetitions too while it shouldn't https://regex101.com/r/K63tsv/1

Comment: But that was exactly the OPs question: The first one SHOULD allow repetitions, the seconds shouldn't. So, depending on what you need, use one or the other.

Comment: I updated the answer to only allow space as separator, since that seems to be the objective.

Comment: finally i understand both regex, it clears my positive/negative lookahead concept. thankyou both :) Christoph &  @revo

Answer (score 6):

Without repetition <sup>[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FjBp2K/3)</sup>

```
^(?:(aaa|bbb|ccc)(?!.*?\b\1) ?\b){3}$
```

And with repetition <sup>[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FjBp2K/4)</sup>

```
^(?=.*?\baaa)(?=.*?\bbbb)(?=.*?\bccc)(?:(aaa|bbb|ccc) ?\b)+$
```

Two more ideas. Regex explanation at regex101 on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

why do you need regex to perform this function though? you could achieve what you want easily by first splitting the strings with delimiter ",". 
You can then create a dictionary object with the words that you are seeking as the keys and values defaulted to -1

Regex 2 can be achieved by looping through the input words and check if they exists as keys in the dictionary object.
Regex 1 can be achieved similarly, just that when a key is matched to the input word, its value would then be changed to 1 and when it is next visited, a false match can be returned.

Comment: u r right, every validation can solve without regex  but i'm intend to solve this with regex if possible. trying to learn advance regex

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regex for uniqueness.

But for separate words in regex, you can use `\b`

Example: `/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b/`

Comment: what about order ?

Comment: @shajji it will work regardless of order. `|` ( alternation ) is same as Logical OR

Comment: u r right, but i'm intend to do some other thing described in question. well thnx for your help :).