# regex to test space separated characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regex that validates "human readable" time format, where it should looks like this:

**1w 1d 1h 1m**

and the accepted time units are (in-case sensitive):

- **w** for weeks
- **d** for days
- **h** for hours
- **m** for minutes

each time unit is optional and should be existed only once at most, so the following formats should be also (for example):

- 1w 1d
- 1w 1h 1m
- 1d 1h 1m
- 1h 1m
- 1w 1m

and this is what I tried so far:

`/((\dw) (\dd) (\dh) (\dm))/i`

the above expression will validate all of the lists formats, but it will neglect the spaces between time units, I want to make the space mandatory between a time unit and another.

Comment: That regex will not validate those strings, it will only match the first unit.

Comment: You may try `\d+[wdhml](?: +\d+[wdhml])+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah sorry, I pasted the wrong one

Comment: Your regex makes spaces mandatory in the input. So, what is the problem? Make them all optional?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it should be not more than one space between each time unit

Comment: Use the regex in my previous comment and remove `+` after space `\d+[wdhml](?: \d+[wdhml])+`

Comment: @revo, it works fine, thank you. but if I want to match floats instead of integers, is there any shortcut of this: `(([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)+[wdhm](?: (([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)+[wdhm])+`

Comment: Are you trying to match or validate? because if validation is done already you could now go for a shorter regex but if you need both at the same time it needs more conditions.

Comment: @revo I want to validate

Comment: The ultimate regex would be `^(?!.*([wdhml]).*\1)\d*\.?\d+[wdhml](?: \d*\.?\d+[wdhml])*$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/kOUgej/1

Comment: @revo thank you, this is the most complete expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For validating those strings you need a more comprehensive regular expression. The following regex matches at both ends of input string and ensures repeating letters are not going to happen using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*([wdhml]).*\1)\d*\.?\d+[wdhml](?: \d*\.?\d+[wdhml])*$
```

`\d*\.?\d+` is used to allow decimals e.g. `1.5` or `.5` (but care it doesn't allow `1.`)

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/kOUgej/1/)

A shorter revision but less readable one of above regex is (credits of such mixing goes to [@bobblebubble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55118802/1020526)):

```
^(?:\d*\.?\d+([wdhml])(?!.*\1)(?: (?=.)|$))+$
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const regex = /^(\d+w\s?)?(\d+d\s?)?(\d{1,2}h\s?)?(\d{1,2}m)?$/

const text = "1w 8d 1h 5m"

console.log(text.match(regex)["input"])

console.log(regex.test(text))
```

```
^(\d+w\s?)?(\d+d\s?)?(\d{1,2}h\s?)?(\d{1,2}m)?$
```

Comment: it matches `1w1d`

Comment: i know it match also `1w8d1h5m` cause the space is optional

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.clear();
dates = [
  // true
  "4w 1m",
  "4w 3d 2h 1m",
  "3d",
  "2h",
  "1m",
  "3d 2h",
  // false
  "4w3d",
  "2h 3d",
  "42",
  "Lorem ipsum",
  "4w 3d 2h 2h",
  "1m 1m"
];


reg = /^\s*(\d{1,2}w\s+)?(\d{1,2}d\s+)?(\d{1,2}h\s+)?(\d{1,2}m\s+)?$/;

dates.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
  console.log(item, this.test(item))
}, reg)
```

Comment: `1h 1m ` should match: > `each time unit is optional`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
regex = /\b\d[wdhm]{1}\b/ig;
match = '1w 1h 1d'.match(regex);
console.log(match)
```

`\b` matches a word boundary.

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary)

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^(?=.*\d[wdhm])(?:\dw)?(?: ?(?<=^| )(?:\dd))?(?: ?(?<=^| )(?:\dh))?(?: (?<=^| )(?:\dm))?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQpvAc/1)

Comment: should `1w 1w` be matched?